# Error with Logging in zend

Tags: windows, apache, zend-framework

```
Hi  This is my code to generate logs 
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('http://localhost/clms/public/log');
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);

$logger->info('Informational message');
```

but am getting an exception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Log_Exception' with message '"http://localhost/clms/public/log" cannot be opened with mode "a"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CLMS\library\Zend\Log\Writer\Stream.php:69
```

Any body please tell me how to make the logs clearly.
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the path to the log file, not a URL, so you probably want:

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../public/log');
```

the error you are getting is because the logger can't write to the path you provided (which makes sense since you gave it a URL). If you are still getting the error after changing this you just need to make sure the directory/log file is writable by the user the webserver runs as.

Comment: Still having the same problem please help

Comment: Have you changed permissions on the log folder or file? Does the log file exist?

Comment: Make sure the log.txt has the writing permission, as you can see the problem is on file opening. Or delete the file and add permission to folder, run script and that should generate log.txt.